# how to read data from an object javascript

Tags: javascript

i have an object `evt.participators` that contains objects. when loggin it , i show this result: 
[image]

I want to read all the  id of  evt.participators objects. I try this code :

```
 var t=0 ; 
 angular.forEach(evt.participators, function(value, key){
 console.log(evt.participators.$id  ); 
 t++; 
 });
```

But i get three time  `undefined`. 
How can i fix it please ?

Comment: `evt.participators` is an `object`..not `array`...

Comment: ahaa hoow can i retreive data from it ?

Comment: Use `for-in` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily retrieve all the keys in the object by using a `for...in` loop

```
for (var key in evt.participators) {
    if (evt.participators.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er647anm/1/

Answer (score 0):

use for..in for loop through object

```
for (var prop in evt.participators) {
  console.log(evt.participators[prop]);
}
```

for more information please follow [For..In Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)